# How to get only 6 item from list?

Tags: android, list, loops

I have a `List<Restaurant> restaurants` (11 items). I want to get only 6 items from 11 items to show in gridview. Now, I loop all size(). How to loop to get only 6 items.

```
if (restaurants != null && restaurants.size() > 0) { 
    for (int i = 1; i < restaurants.size(); i++) { 
      adapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, restaurants);
      grid_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: change  restaurants.size() to 6

Comment: change i < restaurants.size(); this to i  <  6;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way,

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(lotteryList.size()>6){
           return 6; 
        }
        else{
           return lotteryList.size();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
 List<Restaurant> restaurantsTemp=new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
 restaurantsTemp.add(restaurants.get(i));
}
 adapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, restaurantsTemp);
 grid_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> sixItem = new ArrayList<>;
if (restaurants.size() >= 6) { // restaurants.size() (11 items)
   for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) { // 11 items
       sixItem.add(i-1);    
}

} else {
   for (int i = 1; i < restaurants.size(); i++) { 
       sixItem.add(i-1); 
   }
}
adapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, sixItem);
grid_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

if *restaurants.size()* is less than 6 it won't show error.

Comment: It doesn't show only 6 items from 11 items. Do we need to set `i` in adapter?

Comment: @Tr.Buu Do you want to display only first 6 items for all point of time?

Comment: instead of restaurants apply restaurants.get(i) or if it is array pass restaurants[i]. iterator i should be from 0 to 6.

Comment: List have 11 items. I want to show only 6 items in gridview. Later, click see more, will show 11 items.

Comment: you have to restrict the arraylist size to 6 then use adapter no need to iterate every time.

Comment: @Tr.Buu Hi your question and you requirement doesn't match, please update your question as you have updated above in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your `ItemAdapter` `getCount()` or `getItemCount()`

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(lotteryList.size()>6){
           return 6; 
        }
        else{
           return lotteryList.size();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

no need loop if your list already have 11 records.Pass third parameter in adapter constructer and set it into count return as 6 in the adapter.

```
adapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, restaurants,6);
grid_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to use this code, Also you don't need to set adapter in loop.

```
  if (restaurants != null && restaurants.size() > 0) { // restaurants.size() (11 items)
    List<Restaurant> modifiedList=new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i < restaurants.size(); i++) { // 11 items

             modifiedList.add(restaurants.get(i-1));
             if(modifiedList.size()==6){
             break;
           }
        }
      adapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, modifiedList);
      grid_view.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```